# Fastest way to retrieve Http response status in Java

Tags: java, spring, http, rest, httpresponse

I'm doing a little research and benchmark in order to get the Status Code from an Http response.

I need to get response status code from a large list of sites using the fastest way possible, I can't run in multiple threads this will work in a batch process and it's a requisite.

I created a little benchmark service that sends request (avoiding site's cache) multiple times and retrieves time stats.

I'm testing with different clients and APIs but the response times aren't good enough (min 200ms, average: 300 - 400ms).

I test with Java URLConnection, SpringRestTemplate, ApacheHttpCommons, GoogleHttpClient and Restlet.
One problem I've found is that in some of them I'cant request only the HEAD and then retrieve the status sode so I pick full response.

I'm also thinking in sockets and scripts.

Any help would be appreciated lot.

Comment: Why does 'working in a batch process' imply that you can't use multiple threads? And have you tried java.net.HttpURLConnection?

Comment: Sorry but I don't know the logic behind that batch process, it's for my company and I'm not in that project. They only requested me that I must test without multithread. Before that I was thinking in a thread pools and multiple connections.

Comment: Then I would ask them why. Multithreading this is certainly the fastest way possible, unless they want you to use NIO, in which case they should say so, and why.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lack of threading is a bigger problem that those slow response times (which are probably 99% network delay - the particular HTTP library is unlikely to make much difference).

You could try http://mina.apache.org/asyncweb/ which is built on Java NIO, and therefore nonblocking, but it might create threads in the background.

Comment: Ok I'm going to try this one.

Comment: I've also tried apache MINA, jboss Netty and Ning Asynchronous HTTP Client. Better results were using URLConnection, Apache Http Components and Google Http Client with URL Connection implementation (NetHttpClient). But there aren't as good as we expected.

Comment: Yeah but are you using mina correctly? You need to set up a bunch of requests in parallel, then poll their results. Because it's asynchronous, this should be possible in a single thread.